# $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/') not working

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

What am I missing?  Why would the Home template NOT load via `.otherwise('/')`?  If I link to `href="/#/"` or `ui-sref="home"` everything works fine.  However the Home template does NOT load if I try  `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise` is working.  The console does not show any errors.

Another interesting point is the URL is never modified when the first page loads.  My other apps usually redirect from `http://www.domain.com` to `http://www.domain.com/#/`.  This app is not showing the updated URL.

I have tried this in multiple browsers.  No extensions or plugins are active.

Here are my routes:

```
(function () {

    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('myapp')
        .config(configRoutes);

    configRoutes.$inject = ['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider'];
    function configRoutes ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

        $stateProvider
            .state('home', {
                url: '/',
                templateUrl: 'app/partials/home.html'
            })
            .state('login', {
                url: '/login',
                templateUrl: 'app/partials/login.html',
            })
            .state('signup', {
                url: '/signup',
                templateUrl: 'app/partials/signup.html',
            })
            .state('logout', {
                url: '/logout',
                template: null,
                controller: 'LogoutCtrl'
            })
            .state('profile', {
                url: '/profile',
                templateUrl: 'app/partials/profile.html',
            });

    }

})();
```

Comment: If you put something other than above url, then `$urlRouterProvider` in invoked. for example: try `localhost/#/abcdefgh`. however i am still confused what you are asking for.

Comment: Same, Iam also confused. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Are you missing `<base href="/"></base>`?

Comment: @LenilsondeCastro : base tag is present ... after the title

Comment: @PraveshKhatri i've added to the question.  No, nothing added to `.otherwise` loads.

Comment: Which angularjs/angularjs-rounter/ui-rounter version are you using?